# UnsubEvent timestamp

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, unsubscriber

I am creating scheduled job to poll SFMC events queue to get all the newly arrived Unsub/Bounced events via SOAP retrieve API and it works just fine without any filtering. However, when I am trying to apply filter based on event timestamp, I am missing two points:

1. UnsubEvent has number of timestamps like Create Date, Modified Date, Event Date. From what I am seeing in event object, they are stamped with the same datetime value, but still, it would be great to know which one should I use for filtering.
2. The most interesting part is actual timezone, so when event captured by SFMC, it has internal server time. At the same time, my Business Unit has own timezone configuration, and finally when I ran the job I have, there server time of my app.

So, I’d appreciate if somebody helps me to understand that.

Also, in my logs I see that sometimes UnsubEvent appears multiple times for the same SubscriberKey in the overall list, but the actual time is different (~15 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

1. **EventDate** is the timestamp when a tracking event occurred for UnsubEvent,ClickEvent,OpenEvent,BounceEvent,SentEvent.
2. SFMC server timezone is Central America time **GMT-6**. Any date field populated by the system is in this timezone.  So you have to manually cast the Date field to your local timezone.

Comment: BTW, when I am polling unsub events queue, for some Subscribers I can see duplicated events with difference in ~2 minutes. The fact the they have different Object Ids makes me thinking that it’s not duplicity, but rather different events captured by SFMC. So, if you have an idea about such strange behavior, I’d appreciate your help.

Comment: if they are different SubscriberKey then they are not duplicated events. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_unsubscribe.htm&type=5

Comment: The thing is that both events have the same SubscriberKey, but just different ObjectIds (Event Id). And again, it’s not in all the cases, but for some particular Subscribers. So, still trying to understand how it’s possible.